# CLI and .NET versioning

Tags: mono, clr, command-line-interface

Microsoft .NET CLR is an implementation of CLI standard. However, the last publication of CLI standard was made in 2006, but the latest release of CLR was produced in 2010. I understand that work is now in progress on latest version of the CLI specification.

Is it correct to understand that current public CLI specification describes previous version of CLR (2.0) and current version of CLR (4.0) does not yet have corresponding CLI specification.

Does latest version of Mono implement the version of CLI specification, which is not yet published but is complete enough to be able to build CLR-complatible runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current 5th edition (not to be confused with the version of the .NET Framework) of the CLI is specification is not yet final. You can download a working draft here:

> **[ECMA C# and Common Language Infrastructure Standards](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa569283.aspx)**

As the specification is not yet final it is not really correct to say that any product supports it. However, the final version will probably very similar to what is supported by Microsoft in the version 4.0 CLR.